# Component not firing after onMounted is called

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following component, it is a very simple countdown to 0. When the countdown reaches 0 it fires a redirect. When I put this component on my page itself, the onMounted function fires the interval(counterFunc()). When I isolate it into a component the interval(counterFunc()) does not fire. How can I fix this?

```
<template>
    {{ counter }}
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  time: number;
}>();

let counter = toRef(props, 'time')

const counterFunc = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    counter.value--;
    if (counter.value == 0) {
      clearError({redirect: '/'})
    }
  }, 1000);
};

onMounted(() => {
  counterFunc();
});
```

Using it in a template:

```
<AppCountdown :time=10></AppCountdown>
```

Comment: you're not supposed to mutate a prop.  `counter = toRef(props, 'time')` syncs counter to props.time so that even if you do `counter.value--` it's also the same as trying to do `props.time--`.  if you just do `let counter = ref(props.time)` it should work.  if `props.time` is not always available at mount time you might want to also think of adding a watcher

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps, ref, onMounted, toRef } from "vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  time: number;
}>();

const counter = ref(props.time); // set a proper ref that can be mutated

const counterFunc = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    counter.value = counter.value - 1; // mutate the ref as expected
    if (counter.value == 0) {
      console.log("clearError"); // replace with your clear error function
    }
  }, 1000);
};

onMounted(counterFunc);
</script>

<template>
  {{ counter }}
</template>
```

You can try it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-stallman-niiqzl?file=/src/App.vue:0-419